# Symfony2 Many-to-Many relationship sharing one JoinTable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I want to make a Many-to-Many relationship which shares the same join table. I tried the following:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
// ...

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
 **/
private $groups;

// ...
}

/** @Entity **/
class Group
{
// ...
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
 * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
 **/
private $users;

// ...
}
```

This, however, returns the following error when I try to update the tables:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                           
  The table with name 'postgres.user_groups' already exists.
```

How do I create a many-to-many relationship that shares the same table 'user_groups'?

Note: I understand that I can remove the `@JoinTable(name="users_groups")`  but when I do this I no longer have a Many-to-Many relationship with two owning sides. Instead only one side (owning side) knows about the join table.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `@JoinTable(name="users_groups")` annotation from your inverse side entity that is `Group`, Once owning side entity has mapping information then there is no need to define again in inverse side entity, some of the key point related to your question

> The inverse side has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the owning side.
>
> The
>   owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.
>
> You can pick the owning side of a many-to-many association yourself

Reference [`Bidirectional Associations`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#bidirectional-associations)

```
class Group
{

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     **/
    private $users;

}
```

> See [`Many-To-Many, Bidirectional`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)
>   example from documentation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works by creating a owning side and an inverse side, however, I want to be able to create two owning sides. The annotation above lets me do that, but when I update SQL it tries to create the join table twice, which raises the error above.

The documentation talks about create a many-to-many with two owning sides but it does not go into much detail.

Comment: @MarcelTjandraatmadja there will be one owning and one inverse side both entities can't be of owning side also from documentation *Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes* see 4th point [*Association Updates: Owning Side and Inverse Side*](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side)

Comment: I see. So how can I make it both update the join table automatically when they are updated? I.e. when a group is added to a user or when a user is added to a group.

Comment: I found an exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582547/symfony2-doctrine2-many-to-many-relation-with-two-owning-sides-and-doctrine-cmd. But the workaround seems a bit ugly.

Comment: @MarcelTjandraatmadja doctrine will take care itself you just need to implement its method answer for sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726386/symfony2-saves-doctrine-common-collections-arraycollection-in-database-not-the-n/29726877#29726877

Comment: I tried the answer from the other link you provided but Group does not save the User entity unless I also specify @JoinTable(name="users_groups") on its side as well. This, however, creates the original issue posted in this question.

Comment: @MarcelTjandraatmadja how you are saving user on group update your question accordingly but this structure will save users collection on a specific group you need to provide users as arraycollection when saving a group instance